# How to implement BSD Licensed library to MIT License project?

Tags: licensing, mit, license-compatibility, bsd

Currently, i'm facing a problem with library licensing in web development. I have my web project in MIT license. Now i'm trying to use library(javascript) that using BSD 2 License (Source from Github).

After explore the information, MIT and BSD 2 License are similar.

I have license.txt contain MIT license.

Should i append the txt inside with BSD license ?

or

Should i create new txt file "BSDLicense.txt" that contain BSD License? Also, should i call copyright for every external JS file that contain the library ?